# Why doesn't scala have C++-like const-semantics?

Tags: c++, scala, types, constants

In C++. I can declare most things as const, for example:
Variables: `const int i=5;`
Scala has `val i=5`, however this will only prevent reassigning, not changing the object as the following exampe shows:
C++:

```
const int i[]={1,2,3,4};
i[2]=5; //error
```

Scala:

```
val a=Array(1,2,3,4)
a(2)=5 //a is now Array(1, 2, 5, 4)
```

It gets even worse with member functions:
C++:

```
class Foo {
int i;
int iPlusFive() const {return i+5;}
int incrementI(){ return ++i; }
}
```

I can be sure, that calling iPlusFive won't change the object and that I won't accidentally call incrementI on a const object.

When it comes to collections, C++ continues it's const-correct streak with const collections: simply declare your vector as const and you can't change it. Assign a `non-const vector<Int>` to a `const vector<Int>` and the compiler won't copy anything and will prevent you from changing anything in the now const collection.

Scala has scala.collection.mutable.whatever and scala.collection.immutable.whatever, you can't just convert mutable collections to immutable collections, furthermore you're still allowed to change the collected objects with their non-const member functions.

Why does scala, which has an otherwise really great type-system, not have anything comparable to C++ const-keyword?

**Edit:** 
Margus suggested using `import scala.collection.mutable`.
My solution was to use

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
import scala.collection.immutable.{HashMap => ConstHashMap}
```

This will make the mutable HashMap available as HashMap and the immutable als ConstHashMap, however I still like the C++ approach better.

Comment: I am adding this as a comment, as it is not really an answer. The only answer I can come up with is that it does not "by design". The fact is that very few programming languages have the same const-semantics as C++. Some don't have at all, others like Java/C# have a limited form (similar to scala) that blocks code from reassigning to the *reference*, but that provide no guarantee on the *referred* object (primitive types are handled differently in some, and can be made constant).

Comment: +1 Interesting question for a C++ programmer / Scala noob

Comment: Mutating something one just created with intention of using without mutation can be made essentially by mistake, and is not a subject to static compiler check. But pass that something to a method requiring a "non-mutating" interface -- and no mutation will be possible there (even by mistake). So just inheriting from appropriate interfaces will essentially solve the problem.

Comment: C++ itself doesn't prevent me from changing what's referred to  It's undefined behavior to write something like `const int i(5); const int * cip(&i); int * ip(const_cast<int *>(cip)); *ip = 6;`, but that doesn't mean that anything will stop you.

Comment: @David: The CPU's memory protection unit may stop you with an access violation a/k/a segmentation fault.

Comment: If you haven't already you should read http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2010/07/when-constants-vary.html There are some serious limitations to the usefulness and guarantees of const in C++.

Comment: @Ben Voigt:  Entirely correct:  the MMU might give you a segfault.  Or it might not.  Either is perfectly proper behavior, according to the Standard.  This means that C++ `const` affects assignability only, and doesn't guarantee changelessness, like the question's first-paragraph description of Scala's `val`.

Comment: That blog article is reasonably good for explaining the actual effect of `const` vs expectations of people who assume `const` == constant.  If you consider that a function's signature is a contract defining what the caller gives the callee the right to expect, and to change, then suddenly the behavior of `const` (as well as implicit addition of *cv-qualification*) makes perfect sense.  In the alternate world, where `const` means constant and promises the callee that the argument won't change, then the implicit conversion would be to **remove** *cv-qualification*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The thing I dislike about C++ const logic is that it is about the reference and not about the object that is referenced. If I have a "const T *" there is no guarantee that someone holding a non-const pointer will not modify the state of the object. As such, it does not help in any way to avoid race conditions in multi-threaded systems nor does it help in implementing persistent containers.

In my opinion it is very helpful to have a concept of immutable classes and lack of immutable containers in a standard library is a mistake in any language. Since these should exhibit observable immutability but will likely need to be able to change internal/invisible state for efficiency reasons I think const-syntax would be of little help.

Scala has the immutable classes we need to either use directly or base other immutable classes on. That is extremely valuable. Additional syntax might be a nice addition but I can live without it.

Comment: What are you talking about about? const T* - or better T const* as const works to the left makes T constant and leaves T* mutable. So unless someone uses an ugly hack - or you handed a non const pointer out of your class no one can change the data.

Comment: I am talking about being handed a const pointer to an object I do not own or control. Since I do not know if someone else holds a non-const pointer I am unable to modify the object but have no guarantee that it will not be modified.

Comment: BTW: "const int *x" makes x mutable and *x immutable while "int *const x" makes x immutable and *x mutable.

Comment: This <enter>-sensitive behaviour is getting to me... Your variant "int const *x" is a synonym for "const int *x".

Comment: Martin is absolutely right that being handed a const pointer doesn't mean that no one else can change the object.

Comment: Which is what I said, was it not?

Comment: I probably meant to type "@Martin: Silvio is absolutely right"... it was late at night.  @Silvio: However your conclusions are flawed.  C++ `const` definitely lets the caller (aka *controller*) reason about race conditions because it knows which callees have access to the object and whether that is read-only or write access.  Having the callee know whether others can mutate the object leads to synchronization logic in the callee, C++ `const` leads to synchronization logic in the caller, and the C++ way is at least as valid as the other.

Comment: Yes Ben, that is correct but as the caller I can also achieve such by passing a limited interface on the object that only permits read-access. IMO the problem of reasoning about the state of objects accessed concurrently from multiple locations in multiple threads is a much bigger problem to solve than caller/callee logic.

Answer (score 6):

Because C++ const is not that great in complex systems.

> I can be sure, that calling iPlusFive won't change the object and that I won't accidentally call incrementI on a const object.

No, you can't, because the implementation (which may be in a library somewhere out of sight) can cast the constness away. Without const, other languages have to enforce the immutability in safer ways (see Collections.unmodifiableList() in @Margus's answer, for instance).

Const is just documentation that the compiler reads. Documentation is usually helpful but sometimes misleading.

> When it comes to collections, C++ continues it's const-correct streak with const collections: simply declare your vector as const and you can't change it.

Aggregation is where const often breaks down for me. I often want to declare, for instance, that a method will not change the vector but may change a member of it (or return a non-const member reference). I have to make it all const or all nonconst or invent new type variations for every combination.

'mutable' makes up for some of the aggregation issues but introduces more complexity and misuse.

Answer (score 5):

IMO, Scala just gives more flexibility not mixing up immutability of the reference with [possible] mutability of the structure behind it, giving you ability to make a design decision WRT the problem you're dealing with.

Comment: Are you saying C++ doesn't give this flexibility?  This works just fine in C++: `const vector<Point*>& v = getPoints(); v[0]->x++;`.  constness of the data structure (vector) and the content (`Point`) are separate.

Comment: I'm talking about immutability of the data structure vs reference, not data structure vs its content. E.g., you cannot add/remove elements from immutable data structure, whereas mutation of the content (single elements) is possible.

Comment: Which is entirely possible in C++.  If you have a data structure `class Collection { T* elements; public: void const_func(int i) const; }` then there's no problem writing `void Collection::const_func(int t) const { elements[i]++; elements[i+1] = members[i-1]; }`  Within a const member function, `this` has the type `const Collection* const this` and data members become `T* const elements` not `const T* const elements`.  Also of course `const Collection*` is different from `Collection* const` which is the immutability of reference vs immutability of instance question you originally raised.

Comment: And of course if you say `class ImmutableCollection { const T* const elements; };` then the collection really is immutable and no one is adding or removing to an instance after construction.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>All Scala code is translated to Java code, that is why I made examples in Java.</sub>

This is how to do this in Java:

```
    Integer x[] = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4}; 
    final List<Integer> CONST = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(x));
```

So what is happening you ask? CONST is 1 step away from actual array, and it enables to hide actual array and the Collection elements, **where as using a simple array, this would not be possible**. If you would still want to modify constant collection you would need to make a copy of it and modify that.

Source: link

> #### Array with unmodifiable contents?
>
> Java doesn't provide the notion of a
>   const array: that is, an array that
>   can be swapped for a new array (in C++
>   terms, "the pointer can be modified"),
>   but whose elements can't be changed.
>   However, if you need this
>   functionality, the solution is
>   generally much like providing
>   read-only access to any other object
>   as discussed below. So a couple of
>   possibilities are:
>
> - you can create an unmodifiable list by passing a list into
>     Collections.unmodifiableList() (though
>     in this case, the variable would be
>     declared of type List, not of a type
>     that marked it as "unmodifiable"— as
>     discussed below, any attempt to modify
>     it would be spotted at runtime);
> - you can create a wrapper object around a private array, and provide
>     public methods to read but not write
>     its elements;
> - you can use a read-only IntBuffer (or FloatBuffer etc): ...

Source: [Java equivalents - const](http://www.javamex.com/java_equivalents/const_java.shtml) from c++ perspective.

So equivalent for Scala is:

```
    val A = Set(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

```
    val A = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

This should translate to:

```
    scala.collection.immutable.List[java.lang.Integer] A = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

This might explain my response to IttayD comment, why java 6 differs from c++ compiler:

> #### Reified Generics
>
> Currently, generics are implemented
>   using erasure, which means that the
>   generic type information is not
>   available at runtime, which makes some
>   kind of code hard to write. Generics
>   were implemented this way to support
>   backwards compatibility with older
>   non-generic code. Reified generics
>   would make the generic type
>   information available at runtime,
>   which would break legacy non-generic
>   code. However, Neal Gafter has
>   proposed making types reifiable only
>   if specified, so as to not break
>   backward compatibility.

Source: [link](http://tech.puredanger.com/java7/#reified)

Silly to even mention, but Java Constant Naming Conventions is to use uppercase for the variable. Others reading your code will immediately know that the identifier is a fixed, constant value that cannot be changed.

Source: [link](http://www.cwu.edu/~gellenbe/javastyle/constant.html)

> ... you can't just convert mutable collections to immutable collections, ...

A useful convention if you want to use both mutable and immutable versions of collections is to import just the package collection.mutable.

```
import scala.collection.mutable
```

Source: [Scala Collection API](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html)

Not sure what you mean by converting, but you can probably do:

```
val a = scala.collection.mutable.List[Int](1, 2, 3)
val A = scala.collection.immutable.List[Int](a.toArray())
```

Comment: Similar structure should rather be `List` (from `scala.colleciton.immutable`) `val a = List(1, 2, 3, 4)`, that can on demand be converted to array `a toArray`

Comment: Guess your right, I used set to indicate that in constant collection you probably do not want duplicates as well.

Comment: In C++ the compiler checks on const access. Trying to modify CONST in your example will pass compilation and fail at runtime

Comment: That is called **Reification**, and that is just how Java does things.

Comment: "All Scala code is translated to Java code, that is why I made examples in Java." : definitely +1 for not making examples in ARM microcode or smth :)

Comment: The all upper case naming convention is only mandatory for primitive types and strings. For all other types it's optional.

Comment: Scala code is **never** translated to Java source code in the compilation process. It's compiled to Java **bytecode**, and there may not be any Java program that compiles into some of the bytecode that Scala generates.